# Failed to install apache-beam in a brand new anaconda enviornment

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda, apache-beam

I wanted to have a go with apache-beam, I created a brand new conda env with Python 3.8, then I followed the solution in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65710534/how-do-i-inform-conda-to-install-a-later-version-of-apache-beam), I have tried the following commands but none of them works.

```
conda install apache-beam
conda install -c conda-forge apache-beam
conda install -c conda-forge apache-beam==2.31.0
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 apache-beam
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 apache-beam
```

The second and third commands gave me :

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - apache-beam

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Other commands also gave me similar results, am I missing something here? Can someone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Conda Forge feedstock doesn't build for the **win-64** platform. Consider [dropping them an Issue](https://github.com/conda-forge/apache-beam-feedstock/issues) to request Windows builds.

In the meantime, [the Python version seems available through Pip](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-py/). Make sure your environment - I'll call it `my_env` - has `pip` installed, then try installing through there:

```bash
conda install -n my_env pip

conda activate my_env

python -m pip install apache-beam
```